# Understanding a algebraic formula

Tags: group-theory

I have a equation related Burnside's Lemma $|X/G|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|X^g|$.
Can anyone give me intuitive explanation of the equation?Since I'm a novice learner of Burnside's Lemma I need explanation of each term of the above equation.

Answer (score 1):

Here a group $G$ acts on a set $X$. $X/G$ is the quotient of $X$ by $G$; that is, the set of orbits $\{G\cdot x\mid x\in X\}$, or equivalently the set of equivalence classes of $X$ where the equivalence relation is that $x\sim y$ if there is an element $g\in G$ so that $g\cdot x=y$. $X^g$ is the set of fixed points of a group element $g\in G$; i.e. $X^g=\{x\in X\mid g\cdot x=x\}$. So what the equation is saying that the umber of orbits is equal to the average number of fixed points.